# Calculating Elevation statistics for NUTS-3

Tags: qgis, elevation

I downloaded European-wide DTM from https://land.copernicus.eu/imagery-in-situ/eu-dem/eu-dem-v1.1/view

I obtained the NUTS level 3 shapefile from: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts

Now I would like to calculate the following **statistics per NUTS-3 code**:

- the standard deviation of elevation
- average height of the area

How would I do this in QGIS?

The DTM data is very large (~45 GB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Zonal Statistics.

From the Processing Toolbox.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=zonal%20statistics#zonal-statistics

It will calculate (you can choose which ones to calculate):

```
0 — Count
1 — Sum
2 — Mean
3 — Median
4 — St. dev.
5 — Minimum
6 — Maximum
7 — Range
8 — Minority
9 — Majority
10 — Variety
11 — Variance
```

I would do it tile by tile, as EUDEM is provided in tiles. Then rerun for NUTS regions that overlap the tile boundaries with a virtual raster to join the tiles together.

Comment: Thank you @HeikkiVesanto! Just to better understand: if I select a specific EUDEM tile as the **raster layer** and the EU NUTS-3 shape file as the **vector layer** under the zonal statistics and select the statistics of interest, it calculates something. I'm wondering, does QGIS directly interpret this as elevation data or would I need to process it somehow prior? what unit would the output be if I select for instance `2 - mean`?

Comment: Yes. QGIS does not care if it's elevation data or not, the process is the same. The units is meters above sea level in reference to the GRS80 Ellipsoid and vertical datum EVRS2000 with geoid EGG08.

Comment: One follow up question: do raster file and vector layer need to be in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes. They do have to be.